# Attempting a MATLAB program for interest calculation

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to write a super basic program for a homework assignment and I am having difficulty getting started and was hoping for a little help.  Here is the prompt: 
Imagine that you went to the bank and deposited $20,000 in an account that earns 6% 
interest every year, with each year’s interest being deposited back into the account. Write 
a MATLAB program that computes the number of years it would take to accumulate 
$500,000.

So, I know I need to declare a few variables and I want to use a for loop with an if statement because we have not covered while loops yet. Here is my attempt so far:

```
%This program calculates interest accumulated on a given value and the
%years it would take to reach a given goal value

%initial deposit 
Deposit = 20000; 

year = 0;

for year = 1:1:n 
    year = year + 1;
    Deposit = Deposit*(1.06);

if Deposit < 500000


end
```

Thanks all!!

Comment: Do you have to use a loop? There is a well known equation to solve this question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest

Comment: Loop over year instead of i, since that's what is iterating.  For each year, think about how the deposit change during the year (why are you adding another 20000 each year?).  Basically, write the first few years out by hand, then try to modify your code to match your equations.

Comment: Thanks Peter. So my thinking was that I had to calculate the interest then add it to the overall total. That was why I added the 20000 to the Deposit line. Ok, I have edited the code but I'm not sure about the year = 1:n line. Should I define n?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to the for loop here. One is what you originally had:

```
year = 0;
for i = 1:n
    year = year + 1;
    % blah blah Deposit
end
```

In this case, the `i` is counting the number of for loop iterations, and you're incrementing the `year` variable inside the loop. As @Peter pointed out, this is redundant, you can simply use `year` as the loop variable, and then it is automatically incremented by nature of being the loop variable.

```
for year = 1:n
    % No need to increment "year", that is being done by the for loop
    % blah blah Deposit
end
```

I liked your original idea better (it'll generalize better to when you learn about `while` loops). Whatever version you choose, though, it will end up running exactly `n` iterations, which is probably not what you want. In order to stop it early, you need the `break` command:

```
for ...
    % blah blah Deposit
    if (something about the Deposit)
        % We achieved our stop condition, so break out of the for loop
        break;
    end
    % Go on to the next for loop iteration
end
```

When it hits the `break` statement, MATLAB skips straight to the end of the loop.

However, this does raise one concern: you won't know if you exited the loop because you hit `n` iterations or because you encountered the `break` statement. So you should add some kind of check before you assume that this is the value for `year` that you are looking for.